# How to interpret a Dendrogram from hierarchical clustering to find optimal number of clusters?

Tags: r, data-mining, rattle

[image]

When viewing this, how do we know to find the optimal number of clusters? I used K-means and found the "elbow" on the graph that showed the optimal point but I am having trouble figuring this out from just the dendrogram.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation varies depending on your metric and linkage used.

But in general, you want to keep branches that have "many" observations and with a “large" distance above (for the next merge).

Comment: So the ideal way to go would be to find the groupings that have the largest distance between each of the clusters? We use Euclidian distance as our metric.